# Python - How to search word with multiple occurrence and get table result in pdf

Tags: python, csv, pdftotext

I have following pdf and want to search word 'Country', so will get country name and then 'Place to visit' list and convert to csv file.

This is my analysis when you visit a country, which places you must see in any season.
Also get the number of hotels/motels in that places that served vegan food.

Country: USA

The following places of USA you must visit. There are number of hotels that provided
vegan food.

Place to visit:
California      28 hotels
Vegas            9 hotels
New York        35 hotels

Country: Canada

The following places of Canada you must visit. There are number of hotels that provided
vegan food.

Place to visit:
Toronto     22 hotels
Vancouver   13 hotels
Ottawa       8 hotels

Desire result:

USA             California      28 hotels
USA             Vegas            9 hotels
USA             New York        35 hotels
Canada          Toronto         22 hotels
Canada          Vancouver       13 hotels
Canada          Ottawa           8 hotels

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PDF with regular text (and not a PDF with scanned / image pages), then simply do this with PyMuPDF:

```py
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open("mypdf.pdf")
for page in doc:  # itrate over the PDF pages
    words = page.get_text("words", sort=True)  # list word items, sorted in reading sequ
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word[4] == "Country:"  # word string is label "Country:" then ...
            # next word should be the country name
            country = words[i + 1][4]
            print(f"Now dealing with country {country}")
            # whatever else you want to do with country ...
```

The shown `get_text` variant returns a list of items, one item for each string that contains no spaces. Other item components are the position of the string on the page (a wrapping rectangle). So the word items look likethis: `(x0, y0, x1, y1, "wordstring", ...)`.

If your PDF however **does** contain scanned pages, you must OCR it first, and then do the above.
Also possible with PyMuPDF inside the same script, because it contains an integrated interface to Tesseract-OCR.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should use pdf2image to convert each PDF page to an image. After that, use something like Tesseract OCR to convert the image to a string. Once you have that string just create a list of words that you'd like to count their occurrence and use a for loop to iterate through each of these words, using the count() string method to analyze each of the strings obtained from Tesseract and extracting the number of repetitions of each place.